# trying to backup mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I got this code from this site: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/wikis/mysql-tutorials/using-php-to-backup-mysql-databases.aspx

But I'm just a beginner so I don't know what  the config.php and opendb.php suppose to mean. Do I have to create those 2 files in order for this code to work?
If yes, then how do I create it, it isn't included in the site how to create it.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
include 'opendb.php';

$tableName  = 'mypet';
$backupFile = 'backup/mypet.sql';
$query      = "SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '$backupFile' FROM $tableName";
$result = mysql_query($query);

include 'closedb.php';
?>
```

can I just include these lines on the top code so that I will not be putting the include 'opendb.php' anymore:

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("Hospital", $con);
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to back up with PHP, rather than a standard solution like mysqldump?

Comment: I'm trying to create it for users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you need those two files and the other closedb.php included in your script. As the name suggests, config.php most likely contains the DB parameters: user, pass, host, dbname while opendb.php and closedb.php will contain the routines to connect and close your DB.

Comment: The links to the sources of the tutorial you mentioned seem to be broken: http://www.php-mysql-tutorial.com/examples/source/